# How to find first position of substring in a string in C

Tags: c, string

I'm a beginner programmer so forgive me if this code doesn't make a lot of sense. I made a function that tries to find the first occurrence of a substring(toFind) in a string(original). The problem is I have the algorithm down but I wasn't 100% sure how to implement the code. It compiles but it does not work or return anything. Help with my mistakes would be appreciated.

```
int findSubstring(char original[], char toFind[]){

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
bool flag = false;

for (i=0; i<strlen(toFind); ++i){
    for (j=0; j<strlen(original); ++j){

        if (toFind[i] == original[j]){
            flag = true; //set a flag to indicate a potential match
            j = toFind[i]; //set the potential substring position to j

            for (k = 1; k<strlen(toFind); ++k){  //for (k) the remaining characters in substring
                if (toFind[i+k] == original[j+k]){ //compare toFind[i+k] to original[j+k]
                    ++j;//if they are the same move to next character
                    flag = true;
                }
                else{ //if they are different change the matching flag to false
                    flag = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
if (flag == true){
    return j;
}
else{
    return -1;
}
}
```

Example for original = "How are you"

Example for toFind = "are"

should returns 4

Edit: Beginning to think it as something to do with j = toFind[i]

Comment: Sorry but I want to try to make my own algorithm for it

Comment: `i<strlen(original)` is wrong.

Comment: edited so now it only returns -1

Comment: [fix like this](http://ideone.com/H4JCC2)

Comment: @John Smith  I already answered a similar question two days ago.:) See the reference.

Comment: ahh must be the same assignment lol

Comment: @JohnSmith And where do you get these assignments?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow school

Comment: @JohnSmith In what country?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Canada Ontario

Comment: @JohnSmith When you will copy my solution try to make some your own changes.:) Otherwise all your solutions will be the same.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow of course :)